# Triple-Bound Dictionary-Like Data Structure?

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-structures, refactoring

I'm trying to create a data structure that binds 3 elements together, and where any of the 3 elements can be used as the key.

Up till now, I've been using a bunch of functions that convert from one data element to the corresponding others (i.e. MoveStateToAngle, AngleToMoveState, MoveStateToVector2) but it's extremely ugly and verbose.

Update: The data structure is intended for holding less than 10 entries that will never change.

Comment: Please edit your question with the code that you've tried out so we're able to better help with your question.

Comment: After posting this, I realized that an SQL table would have this ability, but I'm looking for something lighter weight that is embedded directly in the code.

Comment: Sounds like you just need three dictionaries to be honest

Comment: @Charlieface Honestly, yeah, if I can't find a better solution, I might just do that. I'd probably want to make some kind of TripleBoundDictionary<> class that does the dictionary duplication elsewhere so that it's not so ugly in the main class, but it would work. The only downside to that is the wasted memory on duplicated elements, but in this case, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Do you need an updateable data structure, or you just want to fill it with data once and then will be frozen?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias The data will never change.

Comment: How many entries (each one composed of 3 elements) do you expect to store in the data structure? I am asking for a rough estimation, not an exact number.

Comment: You should use 3 dictionaries.  Just make sure that you use the same value objects in all 3 so you don't have to duplicate them.  In SQL, you'd have a table with 3 indexes -- same thing.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Less than 10 entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a small number of entries, storing them in a simple array or `List<T>` should outperform storing them in dictionaries. So here is my suggestion. It assumes that the types `MoveState`, `Angle` and `Vector2` are already defined:

```
public class TriDictionary
{
    private readonly List<Entry> _entries = new();

    public readonly record struct Entry(
        MoveState MoveState, Angle Angle, Vector2 Vector2);

    public void Add(MoveState moveState, Angle angle, Vector2 vector2)
    {
        _entries.Add(new(moveState, angle, vector2));
    }

    public Entry this[MoveState key] => GetEntry(key, static e => e.MoveState);
    public Entry this[Angle key] => GetEntry(key, static e => e.Angle);
    public Entry this[Vector2 key] => GetEntry(key, static e => e.Vector2);

    private Entry GetEntry<TKey>(TKey key, Func<Entry, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        foreach (Entry entry in _entries)
        {
            if (keySelector(entry).Equals(key)) return entry;
        }
        throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Key '{key}' not found.");
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
TriDictionary data = new();
//...
data.Add(someMoveState, someAngle, someVector2);
//...
var angle = data[moveState].Angle;     // MoveStateToAngle
//...
var moveState = data[angle].MoveState; // AngleToMoveState
//...
var vector2 = data[moveState].Vector2; // MoveStateToVector2
```

I've avoided using the [`List<T>.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find) method because it requires that the searched `key` is captured in a closure, resulting in needless allocations. That's the reason for the private generic `GetEntry<TKey>` method.

For simplicity the implementation above doesn't enforce the uniqueness of the stored keys.

Answer (score -1):

Depends what you are trying to acheive you can do this with two dimensional `array` or `List<T>` where `T` is an object that hold all three properties.

Then you could easily writ extensions to this `List<T>` that you need.

Very raw example:

```
//element in new dictionary that can store 3 values.
public class NewDictionary
{
    public object value1 { get; set; }
    public object value2 { get; set; }
    public object value3 { get; set; }
}

//Extension that checks if value exists
public static bool KeyExist(this List<NewDictionary> dictionary, object? value1 = null, object? value2 = null, object? value3 = null)
{
    if(value1 != null)
    {
        return dictionary.Any(x => x.value1 == value1);
    }
    else if (value2 != null)
    {
        return dictionary.Any(x => x.value2 == value2);
    }
    else if(value3 != null)
    {
        return dictionary.Any(x => x.value3 == value3);
    }
}

//how to use it.
public Functionality()
{
    List<NewDictionary> list = new();
    //populate list...

    var searchedValue = "test";
    if(list.KeyExist(value2: searchedValue))
    {
        //do stuff
    }

}
```